# Display SVG in its ViewBox size

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am using the `img-Tag` to display SVG images which my users uplaoded to my Amazon S3 bucket.

```
<img src="http://testbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mysvg.svg" />
```

The problem is that, once the image is loaded and shown, it's not the size it was constructed for. For example a test image is displayed with a size of `1920x1920px` but its `ViewBox` is `0 0 128 128`. However, I would like to display the image in the size of its `ViewBox`. In this case `128x128px`.

The only idea I came up with is downloading the image with an ajax request and parse the `ViewBox` attribute out of the svg source. Than I adjust the size. However, I do not want to make any unnecessary http requests and I am looking for a solution to read the images `ViewBox` dimensions. I could use the `<object>-Tag` to load the image but since it's hosted on Amazon I get a cross domain issue and cannot read the svgs source. Even when adding `CORS` rules to my bucket.

Ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CSS to set the size on the `img`?

Comment: @cchacholiades neither codepen nor jsfiddle support `<object>`. However, if you want to at least see some HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/L0n8jo1m/

Comment: @ChrisKrycho I can use CSS, but I first have to retrieve the `ViewBox` of the SVG before I can set the size...

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry about the confusion. You might add a note to indicate that you need the info *for* the CSS to prevent any others' misunderstanding as I did. In terms of a solution, could you just download it as an SVG file, parse the relevant information from it, then set it in the `img`? (**Edit**: I see the issue with extra requests that will cause; sorry.)

Comment: The effect that JSFiddle doesnt support `<object>`?

Comment: As I already stated in my question, I already thought about downloading the image via ajax request but I since I don't want to created some not necessary traffic, I was searching for another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this approach :

- Download the svg file with an Ajax request.
- Parse the viewbox of that svg from the response.
- Create a `new Image();`
- Set the image's src to `"data:image/svg+xml; charset =utf8,"+encodeURIComponent(`the ajax response`)`.
- Set the image *width/height* from the viewBox infos you grabbed step 2 (via css or in its attributes).

That should work for all majors browsers supporting svg in `<img>`, and since you just appended the response string into the image src, **you only make one single request to Amazon's servers.**

So, e.g, it could give you a function like so :

```
function viewBoxedImgSVG(container, url){
    //There might be a better way to parse it...
    var parseViewBox = function(data){
        var parsed = data.match(/viewBox="(.*?)."/);
        if(parsed) return parsed[1].split(' ');
        }
    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var img = new Image();
        // responseText for IE, but doesn't support SMIL in img tag anyway
        img.src = "data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8,"+encodeURIComponent(xhr.responseText);
        var vB = parseViewBox(xhr.responseText);
        if(vB){
            img.width = vB[2];
            img.height = vB[3];
            }
        container.appendChild(img);
        }
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Guys, please read my question as a whole. Quote: `"The only idea I came up with is downloading the image with an ajax request and parse the ViewBox attribute out of the svg source. [..] However, I do not want to make any unnecessary http requests [...]"`. Downloading the complete image isn't the best solution. Paul had a good suggestion with only taking a look at the first couple of bytes.

Comment: Please read the response "as a whole" ;-) **`" you only make one single request to Amazon's servers."`**

Comment: I think I have to apologize - sorry for getting you wrong and correcting you. It's an idea which I already played around before with. However, when you have a `SMIL SVG` which animates some of its content, the CPU is heavily used when the image is loaded using `"data:image/svg.."`. Thus I didn't really wanted to make use of this solution and rather load it from an URL.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about this issue with SMIL animations, I'll have to test it. It sounds like a good question in itself. I'll leave my answer in here however, since it may help some people without this SMIL animation requisite .

Comment: @RobertHahn, I 'm not able to reproduce this SMIL issue… There's no major differences for me on FF 38 and Chrome 42, (maybe I've got 0.5 more fps with the `"data:image/svg.."` version, which doesn't go in your way… Could you give me a link to a file where you do experience it ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/mileselam/pen/kprKm There you go. However, you might only experience this issue when loading more than one SVG. On my website where I experienced this issue I add ~8 SVGs with 2MB each and 2 SMIL animated SVGs as well.

Comment: Tried with ten occurences, and still the same results, of course the cpu frequency got higher but is true for both and still no difference between any way to call the file

Comment: Well, all I can say that when I switched all my svgs from data/ to real urls, my computer and the ones of the other people involved in the project got notably more quiet.

Comment: I took the idea of this answer but instead of rendering the SVG inside an IMG tag, it's added directly into the DOM. Everything works smoothly, even SMIL. The solution isn't the ideal one though and might not fit all program designs but it does work for my use case. The other suggestions Paul made are also pretty good, especially the one with only requesting the first hundereds bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. I am not sure if this works - in general, or with AWS - but you could try doing an AJAX request with "Range" HTTP request header. The idea being that you only fetch the first few hundred bytes of the SVG file.
2. Assuming you are in control of the uploading, you could add the dimensions to the file name. Ie. "mysvg_128x128.svg" and parse the values from the name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The first idea seems to be something I can at least give a try. The second suggestion however won't work for me since I am not in control of the uploading. The users are straight putting their files to S3.